# How do I perform two way MYSQL database synchronization and automated file transfer

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two systems developed using PHP and MySQL database. Both systems run on the Apache webserver.System 1 is a website which is hosted remotely and allows applicants to submit internship applications and various supporting documents with different file formats allowed (pdf, word and png etc). These documents are uploaded to a temporal folder in the remote server where the website is being hosted.

System 2 is a management software in our office. It has some of the tables of system 1 (tables I want information to be syncronized between) and more. 
I want to be able to do two things.

1. Synchronize only specific tables of system 2 (management software) with the database of System one (website).
2. I also want to be able to fetch the uploaded documents from the temporal folder in the online server to a folder in our local server in the office on which the management software runs.

I have been studying the MySQL manual version 5.6 which explains MySQL replication neatly. But it focuses on One-way replication where CU (Create-Update) occur on one database ( Master) and Read on the other (Slave). It seems promising but not enough for my 
situation. I want both databases to allow CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete). Also, I want only a subset of the tables in the management software to synchronize with the database of the website.

I will grately appreciate any idea as I continue investigating.

Comment: google for "MySQL replication".

Comment: What you need to look for is called master-master replication

Comment: Dai and N.B. -- replication might be a good choice (don't know if you can setup only particular tables to be replicated); but if you want to also copy files you need custom code.

Comment: There is to little information to give a good answer to your question... What kind of servers are you using? What are the limits to which applications can run on them? That being said, look for master-master-replication for the DB and rsync for the files...

Comment: Thanks @RichardBernards. I will investigate master-master replication immediately. I have also edited the question with more information.

Comment: SymmetricDS supports multi-master replication, file sync, and MySql.

symmetricds.org

Comment: Thanks @Austin. Just downloaded SymmetricDS. I will see what it can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SymmetricDS** supports *multi-master replication*, *file sync*, and *MySql*.

The free open source version can be found at [SymmetricDS.org](http://www.symmetricds.org)

There is also a Pro version including a gui and support at [JumpMind.com](http://www.jumpmind.com)

Comment: SymmetricDS works smoothly. Master-Master relication suggested by RichardBernard also works perfectly.So if you are not interested in using SymmetricDS software, then you can configure your servers for Master-Master replication.